# Access cookies from Sails.js controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, socket.io, sails.js

How do I access browser cookies from sails.js controller?

This:

```
cookie = req.param('cookie', 'No cookie specified');
cookies = req.param('cookies', 'No cookie specified');
```

returns the default value ('No cookie  specified').

Should I read and write cookies on client-side, or it could be done on server-side somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies in Sails are handled by Express. You can access them by req.cookies res.cookie(name, value, [options]). Check out those two links from new documentation to get more info about it.

- [req.cookies](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/request-req/req-cookies)
- [res.cookie()](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/0.9/reference/Response.md)

Comment: res.cookie() gives write access to cookie, what about read access ?